# TFS Build Server detect user who made checkin

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, build

We have continuous integration on our build server. The program which is automatic tested after every checkin sends some emails. We want to send these emails to the user who made the checkin. Is there any way to get the name uf the user who made the checkin when starting the unit tests.

Best would be, if we can access somehow the name of that user who made the checkin in the AssemblyInitialize Method.

Note: This request is not about sending the test report, it is about changing an email in the configuration file of the application before running all unittests.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the build process workflow to get from the current Shelveset (the type is defined in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll) the OwnerDisplayName (currently it is only the login name with domain so you should do some AD lookup to get the plain name and EMail from AD). 
Once you have this information you can check if the test outcome was gree or not. If not an exception is raised in the default template. Catch it and send mail to the user and rethrow the exception.

At test level it is not possible to see it since TFS has test agents which

1. Can run on another machine thant the build agent (no source code, no sourc control, ...)
2. Can run distributed on several machines in parallel (send failure mail 6 times from your tester?)

You are trying to solve a problem at the wrong level (inside tests). You can change the Build Process template with no issues quite easy.

Comment: thanks for the reply. maybe some more details: the application which is checked in, generates emails and pdf's when some jobs are started. we do test these jobs when running the continuous integration. the recipient of these emails is configured in the app.config file. we want to send them each time to the user who made the last checkin. so he get's the files which are generated after his checkin. but as far as i understand you, that is not possible?

Comment: Hey you are a programmer. Nothing is impossible! But to do it you would still need to modify the build process template to write e.g. this information to the build output folder so the test agent can then access this information. But this does not make much sense since you can do all of this directly in the build process template without the extra loop into your test. I am not so sure if test verification via mail is a good thing. How about checking in the pdfs and comparing them directly in an automated way (e.g. http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html)?